# Where can I find a full description of the "format" field for NumPy objects that includes 'Z' for "complex"?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

When I look at the "format" field for a complex double NumPy object, I see "Zd":

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> ac = np.array([[1,2]], dtype=complex)
>>> memoryview(ac).format
'Zd'
```

However, I don't see "Z" mentioned in the [official Python documentation for "struct"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#module-struct), and I have also been unable to find it in the NumPy documentation, though it's possibly I simply missed it because I couldn't think of anything more likely to find relevant hits than the terms "complex", "Z", and "format", all of which bring up a lot of irrelevant information. Could anyone point me to relevant documentation and/or give me their own description?

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3118/ and https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/623bc1fae1d47df24e7f1e29321d0c0ba2771ce0/numpy/core/tests/test_scalarbuffer.py#L11 may help you

Comment: @Zev, if you made that into an answer, I would upvote it.

Comment: I don't really know enough on the topic to make it into an answer but found that by looking at the source code that produced that result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key documentation is in [PEP 3118, section "Additions to the struct string-syntax"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3118/#additions-to-the-struct-string-syntax), specifically this line:

> 'Z'   complex (whatever the next specifier is)

Thanks to Zev for helping me find the way to that page.

As far as I can tell, the NumPy documentation does mention the unique character codes that specify the real data types (as hc_dev mentioned), but not the fact that in general, the derived complex data types are prefaced by "Z".

Answer (score 0):

The given output represents the **`format` specifiers** returned from given Python's [`memoryview` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview)

`Zd` is apparently the format string for *NumPy*'s (scalar) data type "complex double" [`np.cdouble`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html#numpy.cdouble).

### Related Documentation and Insights

Each of NumPy's data-type defines similar literals as **Character code**, see [documentation of `dtype`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html)

> A unique character code for each of the 21 different built-in types.

Among the [scalar data-types](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html?highlight=Character+code):

- a single **lower-case** character is used for **unsigned** integers and **floating-point** primitives.
- a single **upper-case** character is used for **signed** integers and **complex floating-point** primitives.

For example:

- `'d'` is the character for [`numpy.double`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html#numpy.double)
- `'D'` is the character for [`numpy.cdouble`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html#numpy.cdouble)